# char cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, compiler-errors, char

I am working on an assignment which need to use get and set method to convert the temperature.  However, when I try to write the setMethod, U got an error said that " char cannot be dereferenced". Here is my code;

```
public void setTemp(double temp, char scale){
    // - sets the objects temperature to that specified using the 
    //   specified scale ('K', 'C' or 'F')
    if (scale.isLetter("K")){
      temp = temp + 273;
    }else if (scale.isLetter("C")){
      temp = temp;
    }else if (scale.isLetter("F")){
      temp = ((9 * temp) / 5 ) + 32;
  }
}
```

Comment: `char`s are primitives. primitives have no methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primitives (such as `char`) don't have method. It seems, though, that you're just looking for a simple equality test.

Edit:
As Elliott Frisch noted in the comments, you need to use `this.temp` to reference your data member as the `temp` argument is hiding it:

```
public void setTemp(double temp, char scale){
    // - sets the objects temperature to that specified using the 
    //   specified scale ('K', 'C' or 'F')
    if (scale == 'K'){
      this.temp = temp + 273;
    } else if (scale == 'C') {
      this.temp = temp;
    } else if (scale == 'F') {
      this.temp = ((9 * temp) / 5 ) + 32;
  }
}
```

Comment: Should presumably be `this.temp = `... but that wasn't OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't invoke methods on primitives and char is a primitive!

Use

```
if (scale == 'K')
```

and so on to compare chars.